# Find with exec command which shows the filename

Tags: shell, grep

I'm searching for a text string ("EOF") across a file system. I need to find which files have that string and print the line (for a visual check) and the file name.
So I have come up with this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep 'EOF' {} \;
```

That works but it doesn't print the filename. Next try:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print -exec grep 'EOF' {} \;
```

Now I have also the file names, though all files. I'd need just the file name which matches the grep.
Any help?

Comment: `grep -H` maybe? Or if your `grep` doesn't have that, pass two filenames and it will tell you which one `find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep 'EOF' {} /dev/null \;`

Comment: @MarkSetchell better to use `-exec grep 'EOF' /dev/null {} +` so you can pass multiple names to one instance vs paying the cost to start a separate copy of `grep` for each file

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes. I'm going to pretend  I was envisioning a `find` command without `+` as lame as a `grep` without `-H` 

Comment: Heh. `find` without `+` is actually standard-noncompliant; it's been part of POSIX since about 2008. (POSIX does require `grep` to have `-l`, telling it to write names and nothing else, but doesn't require `-H`).

Comment: Thanks! grep -H did the trick!